# Conflict between arabtex and algorithmic

Tags: symbols, packages, algorithmic

Below is a minimal working example which recreates the problem I'm facing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\RL{d}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE problem
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
 LaTeX Error: 

Command \AND already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

1. I tried to use algorithmicx instead, and the same problem occur.
2. If I comment out the algorithmic section, the document compiles successfully
3. Tried to use savesym as follows but i am still getting
   the same error.

   ```
   \usepackage{algorithmic}
   \usepackage{savesym}
   \savesymbol{AND}
   \usepackage{arabtex}
   ```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It looks like there is no workaround for this issue. I have received the following answer from Prof. Klaus Lagally: "Sorry, ArabTeX and Algorithmic are just incompatible.
They both define (internally) the commands \AND, \OR,
and \NOT, which collide. This cannot be patched,
and unfortunately there is no workaround."

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what I'm doing, but if that you stated in your comment is true, the following example seems to work. (info about the reason is in the comments)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Some text.

\RL{d}

\let\AND\relax
\let\OR\relax
\let\NOT\relax
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE problem
\end{algorithmic}

\RL{d}

\let\AND\relax
\let\OR\relax
\let\NOT\relax
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE problem
\end{algorithmic}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

You can also define this to be automatic (as [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) noted) using the `xpatch` package by including this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\algorithmic}{\let\AND\relax\let\OR\relax\let\NOT\relax}{}{}
```

Comment: Yes, `algorithmic` says `\newcommand\AND{...}`, which is wrong, in my opinion, since these commands are specific for the environment and undefined outside it, under normal circumstances. You can patch the environment to do the `\let`: load `xpatch` and say `\xpretocmd{\algorithmic}{\let\AND\relax\let\OR\relax\let\NOT\relax}{}{}`